# Arbitrary precision spline interpolation

Tags: interpolation, arbitrary-precision, splines

The current implementation of `Interpolation` does not allow arbitrary precision spline interpolation. Yu-Sung Chang says [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4204/280) that "it is not hard to implement it manually for arbitrary precision using `BSplineBasis`."

I am new to splines and not familiar with `BSplineBasis`. **What is the best way to implement arbitrary precision spline interpolation in *Mathematica*?**

I am interested primarily in an analog of the `Method -> "Spline"` of `Interpolation` which I investigated in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30639/280) (BTW, what is the name of such a spline and of this kind of parametrization?). Also, [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/) gives in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898/280) an interesting implementation of a spline with centripetal parametrization, but it is not clear how to use it for interpolation.

P.S. I need an implementation where the degree of a spline is arbitrary. At the moment I am more interested in even-degree splines.

Comment: Yu-Sung's pointer is http://wolfram.com/xid/0c0rpcn4bku6m-dj3q8d, where there are two examples of such a thing (I haven't tested them). What are those example lacking?

Comment: That is an example of cubic B-spline interpolation. I need an implementation where the degree of spline is arbitrary.

Comment: Please see my question about [B-spline Basis Function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/how-to-deal-with-the-condition-u-i-u-i1-in-b-spline-basis-function)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The OP linked to an answer of mine for interpolating over general point sets; for constructing a single interpolating function, a slight modification of my procedure is needed. (In particular, you don't need centripetal or chord-length parametrization in this case.)

Let's start with some data:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1/10, 3/10}, {1/2, 3/5}, {1, -1/5}, {2, 3}, {3, -6/5}};
```

To review the problems with using the built-in `Interpolation[]`, let's try building an interpolating *quartic* spline from `data`:

```
m = 4; (* spline order *)
sp1 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> m, Method -> "Spline"];
```

Now, evaluate:

```
sp1[3/2]
   0.26753591659167364
```

Herein lies the problem: even though the contents of `data` and the argument fed to `sp1` are exact, the output is a machine precision number. Yeesh!

So, we go back to basics and build the interpolating spline ourselves from `BSplineBasis[]`. First, we generate the knots. The clamped condition is the most appropriate for interpolation, so we generate the appropriate knot sequence like so:

```
n = Length[data];
{xa, ya} = Transpose[data]
knots = Join[ConstantArray[xa[[1]], m + 1], 
             If[m + 2 <= n, MovingAverage[ArrayPad[xa, -1], m], {}], 
             ConstantArray[xa[[-1]], m + 1]];
```

To generate the control points for the B-spline, we construct the relevant linear system and solve it with `LinearSolve[]`:

```
cp = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{m, knots}, #2, #1] &,
                       xa, Range[0, Length[data] - 1]], ya];
```

Note that all the entries of `cp` are exact.

At this juncture, you might think that we can use `BSplineFunction[]` on the control points and the knots, but alas, the function also only evaluates at machine precision. We are left with no choice but to use `BSplineBasis[]` once more:

```
sp2[x_] = cp.Table[BSplineBasis[{m, knots}, j - 1, x], {j, n}];
```

Try it out:

```
sp2[3/2]
   25251843/94386740

N[%]
   0.2675359165916738
```

As a verification that we were able to reproduce the control points used internally by `Interpolation[]`, let's do a comparison:

```
sp1bs = Cases[sp1, _BSplineFunction, ∞][[1]];
sp1bs["ControlPoints"]
   {0., 0.777830630128766, 1.3470257035045392, -6.670028631670085, 13.100332135107115, -1.2}

N[cp]
   {0., 0.777830630128766, 1.347025703504539, -6.6700286316700845, 13.100332135107113, -1.2}
```

Certainly, I can't end this post without at least one picture, so:

```
Plot[{sp1[x], sp2[x]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: spline comparison]

```
Plot[sp1[x] - sp2[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: difference of two splines]

I leave the task of bundling everything in a routine as an exercise. If you want to learn more, Piegl and Tiller's *[The NURBS Book](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-59223-2)* is the canonical reference.

Comment: It *is* good to have you back.

Comment: I was able to borrow a friend's computer with a *Mathematica* installation, so I went for it and answered some questions. It was fun while it lasted… :)

Comment: Did you try contacting the Stack Exchange team about the matter?  I understand if you do not wish to pursue it but I think they might help.

Comment: Maybe I'll ask them sometime… thanks for the concern. :)

Comment: @J.M. May I ask you also about a generalization of the spline interpolation (at least) for the 2D case? In the [linked answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30639/280) it is said that "Multi-dimension is simply tensor product version." I do not see this as a *simple* thing but it would be very helpful to have such a generalization. May be a separate thread would be the best place for this.

Comment: If you'll look through the Piegl/Tiller book, @Alexey, one thing you'll realize is that Yu-Sung is correct, except probably for the adjective "simply". As I do not currently have a computer to try the following idea on, you might want to pursue this: if you'll imagine the grid of points as a matrix, you can form an interpolant over each column, and then interpolate on the results of those columns.

Comment: Nevertheless, I do hope my answer was not too late to help you. :)

Comment: Dear J.M, In the textbook *The NURBS Book*, the `knots` owns the following style$$\{u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_p,u_{p+1},\cdots,u_{m-p-1},u_{m-p},\cdots,u_m \}$$Where,$u_0=u_1=\cdots=u_p=a$ and $u_{m-p-1}=\cdots=u_m=b$ , However, in your answer, `knots={{0, 1/10, 1/2, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 3/10, 3/5, -(1/5), 3, -(6/5)}}`(Not the style I mentioned). In addition, I'd like to know what algorithm did you used in your answer. I know there are three methods in *The NURBS Book*. Namely, `equally spaced`, `chord length` and` centripetal method`. Could you explain to me. Thanks sincerely:)

Comment: @Shutao, as I noted in the answer, I used clamped knots; so, I followed the formula you gave. (Note the use of `ConstantArray[]` to implement the ends of the clamped knots.)

Comment: @J.M., Sorry for my misundestanding. I thought that the result of `{xa, ya}` `{{0, 1/10, 1/2, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 3/10, 3/5, -(1/5), 3, -(6/5)}}` is the result of `knots`.In fact, the result of `knots` is `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9/10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}`

Comment: I just translated the formula in Piegl/Tiller straightforwardly into *Mathematica*, @Shutao.

Comment: `data={{0, 0}, {3, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-4, 0}, {-4, -3}};Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 4, Method -> "Spline"]` will failed

Comment: @auto, certainly it will fail; your last two points have the same abscissa.

Comment: @J.M.In fact, this case `data={{0, 0}, {3, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-4, 0}, {-4, -3}};` can interpolate them in two directions, Namely, `Interpolation[Transpose[data][[1]], InterpolationOrder -> 4, Method -> "Spline"]` and `Interpolation[Transpose[data][[2]],  InterpolationOrder -> 4, Method -> "Spline"]`.

Comment: Right, @Shutao; in that case, the procedure of mine linked in the OP should be used instead of the one in this answer.

Comment: @Alexey, if you're still interested in the multivariate generalization of your question, I would suggest writing a new question on it instead of editing this one.

Comment: @J.M. [Done](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84742/280).

Answer (score 13):

Here is my implementation of quadric spline arbitrary precision interpolation which is defined exactly as in `Interpolation` with options `Method->"Spline", InterpolationOrder->2`.

### Theoretical background

Quadric spline interpolation for `n` datapoints is defined as a `Piecewise` function which consists of `n-2` parabolas which are spliced together in the middles of successive datapoints (with exceptions for first and last intervals) by two conditions: successive parabolas at these middle points must be equal and their first derivatives must be equal too. So we have `2(n-3)` such conditions.

Let us designate `j`th datapoint as `{x[j],y[j]}` and define `j`th parabola as

```
s[j_, xx_] = y[j + 1] + b[j] (xx - x[j + 1]) + c[j] (xx - x[j + 1])^2;
```

This definition automatically makes `j`th parabola equal to `y[j + 1]` at `x[j + 1]`. We have to add also 2 boundary conditions:

```
s[1, x[1]] == y[1]
s[n - 2, x[n]] == y[n]
```

And `2(n-3)` splicing conditions:

```
Table[{
  s[j, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2] == s[j + 1, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2], 
  ds[j, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2] == ds[j + 1, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2]
  }, {j, 1, n - 3}]
```

where `ds` is first derivative:

```
ds[j_, xx_] = D[s[j, xx], xx];
```

Now we combine everything together and convert into matrix form:

```
eqs = Flatten[{
    s[1, x[1]] == y[1],
    Table[{
      s[j, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2] == s[j + 1, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2],
      ds[j, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2] == ds[j + 1, (x[j + 1] + x[j + 2])/2]
      }, {j, 1, n - 3}],
    s[n - 2, x[n]] == y[n]}];
arrs = Simplify@
   Normal@CoefficientArrays[eqs, Flatten@Array[{b[#], c[#]} &, n - 2]];
MatrixForm /@ (4 arrs)
```

Looking at the matrices it is easy to see that they have periodic structure and contain only elements of the forms `x[j+1]-x[j]` and `y[j+1]-y[j]` with some numerical coefficients. This periodic structures can be expressed as `SparceArray`s.

### Implementation

Assuming that `data` contains an array of `{x[j],y[j]}`, we define

```
Δx[i_] := Subtract @@ data[[{i + 1, i}, 1]]; 
Δy[i_] := Subtract @@ data[[{i + 1, i}, 2]];
```

Two matrices in the `arrs` can be expressed as follows:

```
bB = SparseArray[{1 -> -4 Δy[1], -1 -> 4 Δy[n - 1], i_ /; OddQ[i] :> 0, i_ /; EvenQ[i] :> 4 Δy[i/2 + 1]}, 2 (n - 2)];
mM = SparseArray[
   Join[{{1, 1} -> -4 Δx[1], {1, 2} -> 4 Δx[1]^2, {-1, -1} -> 4 Δx[n - 1]^2, {-1, -2} -> 4 Δx[n - 1]}, 
    Table[Band[{2 i, 2 i - 1}] -> {{2 Δx[i + 1], Δx[i + 1]^2, 2 Δx[i + 1], -Δx[i + 1]^2}, {4, 4 Δx[i + 1], -4, 4 Δx[i + 1]}}, {i, 1, n - 3}]], {2 (n - 2), 2 (n - 2)}];
```

Now for obtaining coefficients `b[i], c[i]` we can use `LinearSolve`:

```
bcM = LinearSolve[mM, bB];
```

Grouping coefficients with identical indexes together:

```
bcM = Partition[bcM, 2];
```

The intervals at which the parabolas are defined:

```
intervList = 
  Partition[
   Join[{data[[1, 1]]}, 
    MovingAverage[data[[2 ;; -2, 1]], 2], {data[[-1, 1]]}], 2, 1];
```

Now we compile all the spline data in one object:

```
splineData = Table[{data[[i + 1]], bcM[[i]], intervList[[i]]}, {i, n - 2}];
```

`splineData` contains everything that is needed to construct the spline. It contains elements of the form:

```
{{x[i + 1], y[i + 1]}, {b[i], c[i]}, {xmin, xmax}}
```

It is very handy to use `splineData` for exact numerical integration (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18863/280)).

To produce the explicit piecewise function we define the constructor (`HornerForm` is already applied and gives 27% speedup):

```
makeSpline[splineData_List, x_Symbol] := 
 Piecewise[
  Append[Table[{d[[1, 2]] - d[[1, 1]] d[[2, 1]] + 
      d[[1, 1]]^2 d[[2, 2]] + x (d[[2, 1]] + x d[[2, 2]] - 
         2 d[[1, 1]] d[[2, 2]]), #1 <= x <= #2 & @@ d[[3]]}, {d, splineData}],
         {Indeterminate, True}]]
```

It can be used as follows:

```
spline[\[FormalX]_] = makeSpline[splineData, \[FormalX]];
```

Compiling the code for creation of `splineData` into one function:

```
ClearAll[toSplineData, makeSpline];
Options[toSplineData] = {Method -> Automatic};
toSplineData[data_, OptionsPattern[]] /; MatrixQ[data, NumberQ] := 
  Module[{Δx, Δy, bB, mM, bcM, intervList,
     n = Length[data], dataS = Sort[data]},
   Δx[i_] := 
    Subtract @@ dataS[[{i + 1, i}, 1]]; Δy[i_] := 
    Subtract @@ dataS[[{i + 1, i}, 2]];
   bB = SparseArray[{1 -> -4 Δy[1], -1 -> 
       4 Δy[n - 1], i_ /; OddQ[i] :> 0, 
      i_ /; EvenQ[i] :> 4 Δy[i/2 + 1]}, 2 (n - 2)];
   mM = SparseArray[
     Join[{{1, 1} -> -4 Δx[1], {1, 2} -> 
        4 Δx[1]^2, {-1, -1} -> 
        4 Δx[n - 1]^2, {-1, -2} -> 
        4 Δx[n - 1]}, 
      Table[Band[{2 i, 
          2 i - 1}] -> {{2 Δx[i + 1], Δx[
           i + 1]^2, 
          2 Δx[i + 1], -Δx[i + 1]^2}, {4, 
          4 Δx[i + 1], -4, 
          4 Δx[i + 1]}}, {i, 1, n - 3}]], {2 (n - 2), 
      2 (n - 2)}];
   bcM = LinearSolve[mM, bB, Method -> OptionValue[Method]];
   bcM = Partition[bcM, 2];
   intervList = 
    Partition[
     Join[{dataS[[1, 1]]}, 
      MovingAverage[dataS[[2 ;; -2, 1]], 2], {dataS[[-1, 1]]}], 2, 1];
   Table[{dataS[[i + 1]], bcM[[i]], intervList[[i]]}, {i, n - 2}]];
```

Now to construct the spline from `data` we can evaluate

```
spline[\[FormalX]_] = makeSpline[toSplineData[data], \[FormalX]];
```

Any suggestions and improvements are welcome!

### What is so special about quadric spline interpolation?

Quadric spline interpolation *with splicing points in the middle of successive data points* is locally invariant and weakly depends on boundary condition. (But the same is not true for quadric spline interpolation with splicings in data points.) It gives much lesser artifacts than "usual" cubic spline interpolation. Moreover, it seems that splines of higher degree do not give any advantages over such quadric splines. As opposed to cubic spline, data points are not special points at which polynomials are spliced, and it makes much easier exact integration in these points.

Comment: Could you give a demo of your solution? THANKS:)

Comment: @Shutao As you can see from the definition for the parabolas (the first formula in my answer) from which the spline is formed, my solution is non-parametric and so (as well as `Interpolation`) it is not intended for interpolating an *arbitrary* dataset (like [yours](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84717/280)).

Comment: @Shutao My solution does not use `BSplineBasis` and is not intended to be compatible with `BSplineFunction` and `BSplineCurve`. But it has an advantage of being very simple and efficient, mathematically clear and very handy when one needs to perform exact integration of interpolated data (without using `NIntegrate`). Actually I developed my solution exactly for the latter kind of applications.

Comment: @Shutao While I appreciate your solution very much I should note that [your answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84717/280) ([as well as belisarius' answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40174/280)) does not answer the original question because the question is explicitly about creation of arbitrary-precision version of `Interpolate` (preferably with richer set of spline interpolation methods), not about construction of `BSplineCurve` from a set of points.

Comment: @Shutao It would be great if you add a non-parametric version of your solution as another answer: something like `BSplineInterpolate[pts][x]`: `BSplineInterpolate` would accept a list of points as the first argument and return something line `InterpolatingFunction` (in my answer `makeSpline` returns a `Piecewise` function object), the latter can accept the abscissa `x` as its argument and return the interpolated value of the ordinate `y`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply:)@Alexey Popkov. I will have a trial according to the description of your last comment.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11253-014-0990-z) and [this](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/mz/v1/i1/p63), by any chance?

Answer (score 7):

The following is a shameful plug of  [J. M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898/280) that you already linked to show how to get the parametrization by using `BSplineBasis[]` with arbitrary precision and packed into a function:

```
splineInterp[data_, order_, prec_] := 
  Module[{parametrizeCurve, tvals, bas, ctrlpts, knots},
    parametrizeCurve[pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ], a : (_?NumericQ) : 1/2] := 
     FoldList[
       Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^a, Total]];
    tvals = parametrizeCurve[data];
    (*knots for interpolating B-spline*)
    knots = 
      Join[
        ConstantArray[0, order + 1],
        MovingAverage[ArrayPad[tvals, -1], order],
        ConstantArray[1, order + 1]];
    (*basis function matrix*)
    bas = 
      Table[
        BSplineBasis[{order, knots}, j - 1, N[tvals[[i]], prec]], 
        {i, Length[data]}, {j, Length[data]}];
    ctrlpts = LinearSolve[bas, data];
    Return[
      Sum[
        ctrlpts[[i + 1]] BSplineBasis[{order, knots}, i, #], 
        {i, 0, Length[testData] - 1}] &]
  ]
```

***Usage***

```
SeedRandom[42];
testData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> prec];
f = splineInterp[testData, 5, 50];
f[1/10]
ParametricPlot[
  f[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Axes -> None, 
  Epilog -> 
    {Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]], Point[testData]}, Frame -> True
]


(*
  {0.06025513038208479326777055464103084790562316, \
   0.5927955887343273319037301352154452480202510}
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please refer to J. M.'s answer for the details.

---

#### Explanation

**The centripetal distribution:**

[image]

The function `parametrizeCurve` complete this algorithm

```
parametrizeCurve[pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ], a : (_?NumericQ) : 1/2] := 
 FoldList[
   Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^a, Total]]
```

Comment: I do not see in your answer how can I use this as interpolation in a regular way: `interpolation[x]` where `x` is not a parametrization variable `t` but the actual independent variable on which the dependent variable `y` depends by `y[x]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, Please see my explanation

Comment: @ShutaoTang Thank you for the answer to my [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40163/arbitrary-precision-spline-interpolation/84717#comment229802_84717), now I see that the second argument of `parametrizeCurve` may be arbitrary but must be lesser or equal to $1$. BTW it would be better for others if you would post this explanation under your own answer. :^)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, My pleasue. I used the `chord-length` method to generate the parameters in my answer,  so I think it is suitable to place this explanation in belisarius's answer:-)