# Multidimensional arbitrary precision spline interpolation on the grid

Tags: interpolation, splines, arbitrary-precision

This question is a generalization of the [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40163/280) one for multiple dimensions. In the answer to that question an implementation for the clamped spline interpolation for 1D case and arbitrary degree of spline is given. How can it be extended for multidimensional case?

Comment: I've figured out how to handle two and three variables, but I'm having difficulty extending it to an arbitrary number of dimensions. If it's okay with you, I can post the incomplete solution.

Comment: What does the `arbitrary precision` mean? Could you give the difinition or a demo to show `arbitrary precision interpolation`? Or I would like to know which case did you need to  `arbitrary precision interpolation`?

Comment: @Shutao You could easily find the answer in the Documentation: "[Arbitrary‐Precision Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html)," "[Arbitrary‐Precision Calculations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html)" or in Wikipedia: "[Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)." An example of arbitrary precision interpolation with short discussion is given in [previous answer by J.M.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240/280).

Comment: In fact, @AlexeyPopkov the `MachinePrecsion` is enough in my work.

Comment: Here's one possible reason to use arbitrary precision: if you're using Gröbner basis methods to find intersections of B-spline surfaces (they are, after all, piecewise polynomials!), it is useful to have a representation that can work with exact or arbitrary-precision arithmetic, since these methods can sometimes be sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

I still haven't figured out how to write a routine for arbitrary *dimension*, but I'm posting my (incomplete!) solution in case people might have ideas on extending what I have.

---

### Bivariate interpolant

Here is a random bivariate polynomial, which we'll use for generating test data:

```
f[x_, y_] := -2 + 4 x^2 + 4 x^3 - 3 y - 5 x^2 y + 5 y^2 + 5 x y^2 + y^3
```

Here's some test data from `f[x, y]`, sampled at non-equispaced points:

```
da = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, f[x, y]},
                   {x, {-2, -4/3, -1/5, 1/9, 3/4, 1}},
                   {y, {0, 1/6, 3/8, 9/5, 2}}], 1];
```

Here's the reference interpolating function:

```
{p, q} = {2, 3}; (* spline degrees in the two variables *)
ipf = Interpolation[da, InterpolationOrder -> {p, q}, Method -> "Spline"];
```

Some preliminary processing to separate out independent and dependent variables:

```
{pts, vals} = Transpose[SplitBy[SortBy[da, First], #[[1, 1]] &], {3, 2, 1}];
```

Make the knot sequence for each independent variable:

```
makeKnots[list_?VectorQ, deg_Integer?NonNegative] := 
          With[{n = Length[list]}, 
               Join[ConstantArray[list[[1]], deg + 1], 
                    If[deg + 2 <= n, MovingAverage[ArrayPad[list, -1], deg], {}], 
                    ConstantArray[list[[-1]], deg + 1]]]

{u, v} = {pts[[1, All, 1]], pts[[All, 1, 2]]};
{uk, vk} = MapThread[makeKnots, {{u, v}, {p, q}}];
```

Build the control points:

```
{m, n} = {Length[u], Length[v]};
usol = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{p, uk}, #2, #1] &,
                         u, Range[0, m - 1], 1]];
vsol = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{q, vk}, #2, #1] &,
                         v, Range[0, n - 1], 1]];

cpts = vsol /@ Transpose[usol /@ vals];
```

Finally, the bivariate interpolating spline:

```
spf[x_, y_] = Fold[Dot, cpts, {Table[BSplineBasis[{q, vk}, k - 1, y], {k, n}], 
                               Table[BSplineBasis[{p, uk}, k - 1, x], {k, m}]}];
```

Plot the two interpolants and the original function:

```
MapThread[Plot3D[#1[x, y], {x, -2, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> #2] &,
          {{f, ipf, spf}, {"True", "InterpolatingFunction", "B-spline"}}]
// GraphicsRow
```

[image: comparison of interpolants]

Evaluate `ipf[]` and `spf[]` at the same argument:

```
{ipf[-1, 1], spf[-1, 1]}
   {-8.59478, -552429212/64275003}
```

Note that only the second function gave exact output.

The difference between `ipf[]` and `spf[]`, showing good agreement:

```
Plot3D[ipf[x, y] - spf[x, y], {x, -2, 1}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: difference between two interpolants]

If you want further confirmation, you can try recovering the control points and knots from `ipf[]`, using a procedure similar to the one in [my previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240), and compare them with the control points and knots I generated here.

---

### Trivariate interpolant

Hopefully, you can see the similarities and differences between the previous example and this one:

```
(* random polynomial *)
mp[x_, y_, z_] := 3 - 7 x^2 + 2 x^3 - 2 y + 8 y^2 + 5 x y^2 + 8 y^3 + 4 x y^3 -
                  2 y^4 + 6 x z + 2 x^2 z - 6 x^3 z + 2 y z + 4 x y z -
                  2 x^2 y z - 3 y^2 z - 8 x y^2 z + 7 y^3 z - 5 z^2 + x z^2 +
                  2 x^2 z^2 + 6 y z^2 - 4 y^2 z^2 + 9 z^3 - 4 x z^3 -
                  3 y z^3 - 9 z^4
(* random data *)
da = Flatten[Table[{{x, y, z}, mp[x, y, z]}, {x, {-2, -3/2, -9/7, 7/9, 2, 3}},
                   {y, {1, 5/3, 5/2, 9/2, 5}}, {z, {-1, 5/7, 11/10, 2}}], 2];

{p, q, r} = {4, 3, 2}; (* B-spline degree for each variable *)
ipf = Interpolation[da, InterpolationOrder -> {p, q, r}, Method -> "Spline"];

{pts, vals} = Transpose[GatherBy[da, {#[[1, 1]] &, #[[1, 2]] &}], {4, 3, 2, 1}];

(* make knots *)
{u, v, w} = {pts[[1, 1, All, 1]], pts[[1, All, 1, 2]], pts[[All, 1, 1, 3]]};
{uk, vk, wk} = MapThread[makeKnots, {{u, v, w}, {p, q, r}}];

(* make control points *)
{l, m, n} = Length /@ {u, v, w};
usol = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{p, uk}, #2, #1] &, u, Range[0, l - 1], 1]];
vsol = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{q, vk}, #2, #1] &, v, Range[0, m - 1], 1]];
wsol = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{r, wk}, #2, #1] &, w, Range[0, n - 1], 1]];
cpts = Map[wsol, Transpose[Map[vsol,
           Transpose[Map[usol, vals, {2}], {2, 3, 1}], {2}], {1, 3, 2}], {2}];

(* B-spline interpolant *)
spf[x_, y_, z_] = Fold[Dot, cpts, {Table[BSplineBasis[{r, wk}, k - 1, z], {k, n}], 
                                   Table[BSplineBasis[{q, vk}, k - 1, y], {k, m}], 
                                   Table[BSplineBasis[{p, uk}, k - 1, x], {k, l}]}];
```

Tests:

```
{ipf[2, 3, 1], spf[2, 3, 1]}
   {383.531, 10447533501473/27240371550}

ContourPlot3D[#[x, y, z], {x, -2, 3}, {y, 1, 5}, {z, -1, 2}, 
              BoxRatios -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 0] & /@
{ipf, spf} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: 3D contours of different interpolants]

Comment: The program in **Trivariate interpolant** was very time-consuming.

Comment: Agreed. For some reason, it seemed faster in version 8 than in version 10…

Comment: Although the precision of `usol` is `Infinity`, when you use `ContourPlot3D`, the precison will change to the `MachinePrecison`. In addition, you use the property of B-spline basis. Namely, In generally, when $u_0 \in \left[u _i ,u _{i+1} \right)$, the B-spline function basis $N_{i-p,p},\cdots ,N_{i,p}$ are not equal to 0.

Comment: That's correct. The only reason for showing the plot is to visually demonstrate that the explicitly-constructed B-spline is equivalent to the output of `Interpolation[]`. If you want to force the use of higher precision, the plotting functions all accept a `WorkingPrecision` setting. The explicitly constructed B-spline will keep up; the `InterpolatingFunction[]` will still be stuck at `MachinePrecision`.

Comment: Lastly, I would like to say that there is no need to construct the **arbitrary precision interpolation** own to that `MachinePrecision` is enough for our general work.

Comment: @Shutao, I wouldn't be that confident. :) Sometimes, there are situations where `MachinePrecision` can be insufficient (e.g. finding intersections); it's always useful to have a safeguard against loss of significant digits.

Comment: BTW, Did you know how to deduce the following recursive formula about the derivative of B-spline basis $$
\frac{d}{du}N_{i,p}(u)=p\left[ \frac{N_{i,p-1}(u)}{u_{i+p}-u_i}-\frac{N_{i+1,p-1}(u)}{u_{i+p+1}-u_{i+1}} \right] 
$$ I can understand the *verification process* by mathematical induction that the author given in the textbook. However, I would like to know **where this formula came from**. Namely, how to deduce it directly?

Comment: @Shutao, I don't have my books with me, but with these things, one usually starts with looking at the low order cases, trying to determine a pattern, and then proving said pattern inductively.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, @J.M. this recursive formula could been proven with **mathematical induction**. Namely, (1)varifying the formula when $p=1$ (2) Assuming this formula is right for $p=k$, then proved that this formula is also right for $p=k+1$ with help of assumption. However, I would like to know **how the first people discovered this recursive formula**. i.e. How to **deduce** it?, rather than **proving** it?

Comment: @Shutao, to repeat what I said: "look at the low order cases, try to determine a pattern"; sometimes, one just starts by guessing. :) As a simpler example: if you keep differentiating $x^k$ $n$ times for various small values of $k$ and $n$, you'll eventually notice the pattern $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}x^{k-n}$, which you then proceed to prove inductively. A lot of work in combinatorics actually proceeds in this way.