# Produce a spline from a set of {{x, y}, z} points and get its parameters/expression

Tags: interpolation, splines

I have produced a set of points in a variable of the type `{{x1, y1}, z1},{{x2, y2}, z2}, ,... }`, where `{x, y}` should be the arguments of the function and `z` is the associated value. What I need to obtain is the continuous function in order to generate `z` for any value of `{x, y}` in the domain implicit in the data.

As I understand it, a good way to do this would be to use a 2D Spline. 
At first I had an unstructured grid, but with the help of the community, now I've produced a grid and values of this form (the real list has been "thinned"):

```
{{{0.11, 0.1}, 0.621687}, {{0.11, 0.3}, 0.674455}, {{0.11, 0.5}, 0.743462}, 
 {{0.11, 0.7}, 0.803179}, {{0.11, 0.9}, 0.843444}, {{0.11, 1.1}, 0.866607}, 
 {{0.11, 1.3}, 0.881172}, {{0.11, 1.5}, 0.890488}, {{0.11, 1.7}, 0.896887}, 
 {{0.11, 1.9}, 0.901538}, {{0.11, 2.1}, 0.905067}, {{0.11, 2.3}, 0.907836}, 
 {{0.11, 2.5}, 0.910066}, {{0.11, 2.7}, 0.911902}, {{0.11, 2.9}, 0.913404},
 (*==============delimiter==================*) 
 {{0.15, 0.1}, 0.15}, {{0.15, 0.3}, 0.15}, {{0.15, 0.5}, 0.15}, 
 {{0.15,0.7}, 0.414754}, {{0.15, 0.9}, 0.648793}, {{0.15, 1.1}, 0.768185}, 
 {{0.15, 1.3}, 0.832127}, {{0.15, 1.5}, 0.862517}, {{0.15, 1.7}, 0.879246}, 
 {{0.15, 1.9}, 0.889989}, {{0.15, 2.1}, 0.897541}, {{0.15, 2.3}, 0.90316}, 
 {{0.15, 2.5}, 0.907512}, {{0.15, 2.7}, 0.910985}, {{0.15, 2.9}, 0.913761},
 (*==============delimiter==================*) 
 {{0.19, 0.1}, 0.19}, {{0.19, 0.3}, 0.19}, {{0.19, 0.5}, 0.19},
 {{0.19,0.7}, 0.19}, {{0.19, 0.9}, 0.402054}, {{0.19, 1.1}, 0.658819}, 
 {{0.19, 1.3}, 0.81877}, {{0.19, 1.5}, 0.871256}, {{0.19, 1.7}, 0.88874}, 
 {{0.19, 1.9}, 0.898598}, {{0.19, 2.1}, 0.905459}, {{0.19, 2.3}, 0.910567}, 
 {{0.19, 2.5}, 0.914527}, {{0.19, 2.7}, 0.917694}, {{0.19, 2.9}, 0.920228}}
```

Further, I use:

```
fspl = Interpolation[Xac, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

and obtain, in principle, satisfying results if I could get the expression for the spline (for use outside *Mathematica*). Searching on stackexchange shows that people have had similar problems, but I found no evident solution. I tried to use `fspl["Methods"]`, but the list it returns does not seem to be really helpful.

Comment: Look up `Interpolation[]`.

Comment: After I've transformed the data to {{x1,y1},z1},{{x2,y2},z2},... and use Interpolation I get the error "There are duplicated abscissa points in"... But I intend to have duplicate x or y values...

Comment: @user14679 - but it wouldn't make sense for there to be exactly duplicated `{x, y}` pairs with different z values.  Also, `Interpolation` will not give you the form of the interpolating function, it will just allow you to get values in between your grid points.  To actually get the spline function is a nontrivial task.

Comment: Oh, but my real aim is to get the spline function expression, because I will further use it out of Mathematica.

Comment: And I don't seem to have exactly equal {x,y} values, they are equal only separately...

Comment: You do have equal $\{x,y\}$ pairs. With the above data assigned to `dat` then `Select[# > 1 &]@Counts[Most /@ dat]` selects one such duplicate pair.

Comment: perhaps that was fixed in editing, but I don't see any dups. @user14697 I'd suggest you post an example dataset that is small enough to include in its entirety.

Comment: Thank you, yes, the dups where removed, as you advise, I've edited the post, adding real, but thinned, data.

Comment: `fspl["InterpolationMethod"] (* BSpline *)`.   I think the question is essentially how to get the control points for the b-spline surface.  Unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: @george2079 Please see my answer for solving the **control points** of the B-spline surface.-:)

Answer (score 10):

I have done [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240) [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97330) in some previous spline-related threads, but here it is again:

```
fspl = Interpolation[Xac, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2];

fb = First[Cases[fspl, _BSplineFunction, ∞]];
{sd, scpts, sk} = fb /@ {"Degree", "ControlPoints", "Knots"};

(* explicitly constructed B-spline surface *)
ip[x_, y_] = Fold[#2.#1 &, scpts, 
                  MapThread[Table[BSplineBasis[{#1, #2}, k - 1, #3], {k, #4}] &,
                            {sd, sk, {x, y}, Dimensions[scpts]}]];
```

Compare:

```
{fspl[0.16, 2.3], ip[0.16, 2.3]}
   {0.9038789687499998, 0.90387896875}
```