# Dump Curvature Information for 3d Models

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, mesh

Is anyone aware of any utility to generate and dump Principal, Gaussian and Mean Curvatures for a 3D Model or a set of points? I have reserched following tools -

meshlab
cloudcompare
They are able to compute the curvatures, but they do not have the option to dump it.

I need to get this information for my dataset which consists of like 200 models and would need to dump the curvature info for the same.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: See [(117884)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117884), [(127975)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127975) -- is this even a question about the software product, Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: @m_goldberg - I am not sure if I am asking the question in write forum. I am have posted the same question in the main stackoverflow site, but haven't received any response. 

I posted here, thinking there might be any mathematical library or software, which can help me dump the curvatures at each point of a 3D mesh. 

I am all for making the comunity better, so let me know if I should take down the question from here.

Comment: Try `ResourceFunction["GaussianCurvature"][surf[u, v], {u, v}]` with 3D-surface `surf[u,v]` .

Comment: `ResourceFunction["MeanCurvature"][surf[u, v], {u, v}]` with 3D-surface surf[u,v]