# NURBS model from a entire mesh

Tags: mesh, splines

I have a mesh in STL file format and imported it into Mathematica.

```
data=Import["mesh.stl"];
```

or

```
data = Import["mesh.stl", "VertexData"];
```

Using programs like SolidWorks or similar ones, you can easily generate NURBS surface from meshes. Until now, I didn't find any possibility to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange! Is your question "how do I generate a NURBS surface from a mesh?" or something like it? Can you please edit your question to ask a specific question? (You may find the documentation and other M.SE questions relating to `BSplineSurface` useful.)

Comment: Check out [BSplineSurface](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineSurface.html) and [BSplineFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) and [Splines guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Splines.html)

Comment: @Hans Ulli, can stl file generate NURBS surface in Solidworks?

Comment: This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140601/how-to-fit-b-splines-to-unstructured-grids-triangulated-surfaces) is related, although still no answers - The problem I think is that currently the b-spline fitting is only for structured grids of points (rectangular), and this is not the case for triangulated surfaces

Comment: I tried BSplineSurface, but wasn't able to create surfaces.