# What's the difference between Interpolation[pts, Method -> Spline] and BSplineCurve?

Tags: interpolation, splines

Last month, I answered a question about *spline interpolation*,please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40163/arbitrary-precision-spline-interpolation/84717#84717)

Now I do the following operations

```
pts=
  {{0, 0.}, {3, 4}, {-1, 5}, {-4, 0}, {-5, -3}, {-10, -11}, {-11, -12}}
xy = Interpolation[pts, Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 4];

graph1=
  Plot[xy[t], {t, Min[pts[[All,1]]], Max[pts[[All,1]]]}, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-15, 10}}]
```

> [image]

However, when I used my function `visualizeBSpline`, it given a different result.

```
graph2 = visualizeBSpline[pts, 4, ImageSize -> 300]
```

> [image]

```
Show[{graph1,graph2}]
```

> [image]

#### Question

- Why the result of `Interpolation[pts, Method -> "Spline"]` is different from `BSplineCurve`.
- How to make the result of `Interpolation[pts, Method -> "Spline"]` and `BSplineCurve` same.

---

#### Edit

Thanks for *march's* hint

```
graph3 =
  visualizeBSpline[Sort[pts], 4, ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-15, 16}}]
```

> [image]

When I sort the `pts`, the results of `Interpolation` and `BSplineCurve` are still *different*.

```
Show[{graph3, graph1}]
```

> [image]

Comment: What do you get if you do instead `visualizeBSpline[Sort[pts], 4, ImageSize -> 300]`?

Comment: A interpolation function must represent a single-vaued function of one variable. A BSpline is not a function but the parametric representation of a curve. Why do you think their plotted trace should look the same?

Comment: @m_goldberg, At first, When I know the `Interpolation` has the `Method->Spline`, I think they use the same theory *The NURBS*, so I simply think their result should be same .

Comment: @march, Thanks for your hint. BTW, is it possible to let the `Interpolation` *unsort*  the `pts`.

Comment: You've seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240)?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.Yes, last month when I saw your answer, then I came up with my [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40163/arbitrary-precision-spline-interpolation/84717#84717)

Comment: Then, you realize that all the ingredients for making the spline are already there…

Comment: @ShutaoTang. I don't think so, for exactly m_goldberg's reason.

Answer (score 4):

As *m_goldberg* said in the comment

> A interpolation function must represent a `single-vaued function` of one variable. A `BSpline` is not a function but the `parametric representation` of a curve

To achieve the *same* interpolation result, I must interpolate the data `in two directions`.

The `interpolateCurve` function gives the interpolation of curves.

> [image]

```
Options[interpolateCurve] = 
  Join[Options[ParametricPlot3D], Options[Interpolation]];

interpolateCurve[pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{order, x, y, s, func1, func2},
    order = OptionValue[InterpolationOrder];
    x = pts[[All, 1]];
    y = pts[[All, 2]];
    (*calculate the accumulative chord length*)
    s =
     FoldList[
       Plus, 0, EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]];
    (*interpolation points with spline-method in two directions*)
    {func1, func2} =
      Interpolation[
       Thread@{s, #}, InterpolationOrder -> order, Method -> "Spline"] & /@ {x, y};
    (*visualize the curve*)
    ParametricPlot[{func1[t], func2[t]}, {t, 0, Last[s]},
     Evaluate@
      (Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]), 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]}]
  ]
```

**Test**

```
curvepoints = {{0, 0.}, {3, 4}, {-1, 5}, {-4, 0}, {-4, -3}, {-10, -11}, {-11, -12}};

{interpolateCurve[curvepoints, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-15, 10}}],
 visualizeBSpline[curvepoints, 3, ImageSize -> 300]}
```

> [image]

```
Show[%]
```

> [image]

```
pts={{0, 0.}, {3, 4}, {-1, 5}, {-4, 0}, {-5, -3}, {-10, -11}, {-11, -12}};

{interpolateCurve[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 3, ImageSize -> 260, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-15, 10}}],
visualizeBSpline[pts, 3, ImageSize -> 260]}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

My answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84240) is effectively an answer to this question as well; I'll leave to other people the decision of whether to close this as a dupe. Details on the proceedings can be read in my other answer. Here, I will merely present results:

```
pts = SortBy[{{0., 0.}, {3., 4.}, {-1., 5.}, {-4., 0.}, {-5., -3.},
              {-10., -11.}, {-11., -12.}}, First];

m = 4; n = Length[pts];
{xa, ya} = Transpose[pts];
knots = Join[ConstantArray[xa[[1]], m + 1], 
             If[m + 2 <= n, MovingAverage[ArrayPad[xa, -1], m], {}], 
             ConstantArray[xa[[-1]], m + 1]];
cp = LinearSolve[Outer[BSplineBasis[{m, knots}, #2, #1] &, xa,
                       Range[0, Length[pts] - 1]], ya];

if = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> m, Method -> "Spline"];
sf = BSplineFunction[List /@ cp, SplineDegree -> m, SplineKnots -> knots];

Plot[{if[x], sf[x]}, {x, -11, 3}, Axes -> None, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], RGBColor[7/19, 37/73, 22/31]],
                Point[pts]}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], RGBColor[7/19, 37/73, 22/31]], 
                   Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], RGBColor[59/67, 11/18, 1/7]]}]
```

[image: two splines]

```
Plot[if[x] - sf[x], {x, -11, 3}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[7/19, 37/73, 22/31]]
```

[image: they look the same, don't they?]