# Joining ordered set of points with splines in spiral

Tags: plotting, graphics, splines

I have a collection of points

```
{{-0.137445, -0.0103507}, {-0.0452845, 0.0343154}, {0.30498, -0.0118266}, {-0.0224633, 0.0197979},
 {-0.168469, -0.0197066}, {0.0973217, 0.0478612}, {-0.0441388, 0.0360607}, {0.185982, -0.0679699},
 {0.0185057, 0.0245944}, {-0.129016, 0.0581276}, {0.0759223, -0.0514376}, {0.123763, 0.0743706}, 
 {-0.0324282, 0.0267871}, {-0.107764, -0.100215}, {0.0885256, 0.0232463}, {-0.0353817, 0.110461}, 
 {-0.111862, -0.00308756}, {0.267131, -0.0401582}, {0.0665588, 0.0494041}, {-0.103328, 0.0535261},
 {-0.107966, -0.105811}, {0.112237, 0.0221174}, {0.0250018, 0.153274}, {-0.0569079, 0.0282354}, 
 {0.0635016, -0.142617}, {0.146519, 0.027247}, {-0.0235671, 0.0778935}, {-0.167359, 0.0314445}, 
 {0.0472315, -0.0944644}, {0.166657, 0.0808811}, {0.0127167, 0.126777}, {-0.0896872, 0.00085879}, 
 {0.0468778, -0.181101}, {0.0641557, 0.00642259}, {-0.00698507, 0.172202}, {-0.112879, 0.0671148}, 
 {-0.00809596, -0.12273}, {0.211062, 0.0186191}, {0.0619741, 0.117436}, {-0.0725547, 0.0468807}, 
 {-0.129253, -0.139777}, {0.124918, -0.0620453}, {0.0761669, 0.129845}, {-0.0510648, 0.1879}, 
 {-0.063928, -0.0156006}, {0.133047, -0.178149}, {0.140128, 0.0330165}, {0.00229768, 0.129346}, 
 {-0.122887, 0.0639973}, {-0.079265, -0.156894}}
```

that look like this

[image]

They are ordered in some sort of spiral, and I would like to join them with splines as shown below

[image]

The points are ordered clockwise (starting from 50 going backwards), and I would like the piecewise curves to be joined as smoothly as possible (doing another circuit if necessary before joining to the next point). How would I go about doing this?

## Update

@kguler's answer is great, but doesn't join all of the points:

[image]

Is there a way to ensure the spline passes *through* each point?

Comment: [I would normally put this in a comment, but my reputation on this part of Stack is not high enough.]
I assume you have tried using something like `Fit[data,{1,x,x^2,x^3},x]` for a cubic spline already? You could also find the convex hull for 4, 5, or 6 point sets inside your list and then model the fit to an ellipse. Then take the set of ellipses and smoothly interpolate them together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The built-in functionality can do this directly:

```
{xs, ys} = Transpose[points];
xinterp = Interpolation[xs, Method -> "Spline"];
yinterp = Interpolation[ys, Method -> "Spline"];
ParametricPlot[{xinterp[t], yinterp[t]}, {t, 1, Length@points}, Epilog -> Point /@ points]
```

[image]

Without the `"Spline"` method, the interpolating functions are not always differentiable, which creates corners in the plot. The `"Spline"` method gives a differentiable function (actually twice-differentiable, since the default `InterpolationOrder` is 3). More information here: [How does Interpolation really work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4204/484)

Comment: I also tried this. With bigger `InterpolationOrder` it looks good enough :)

Comment: Ah, yes, but then it begins overshooting a lot.

Comment: It turns out that nondifferentiability is only a problem if you don't use the `"Spline"` method. I wonder why the documentation doesn't mention this.

Comment: Great! Indeed, there is *the curves appear close, but the spline has a continuous derivative* in docs (`Method` section for `Interpolation`).

Comment: @ybeltukov, that is very noble of you ;) I will take a close look & compare ...

Comment: @ybeltukov, yes, must agree, curves are "more natural" (highly technical term, that ;))

Comment: @ybeltukov: Ah, there is that. But under "Possible Issues" it says that the interpolating function may not be differentiable, without mentioning that the spline method does not have this issue.

Comment: It might be worth remarking that one can get a single interpolation of the curve with `xyfn = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, points], Method -> "Spline"]`.

Answer (score 12):

I appreciate kguler's elegant solution, but it doesn't join the points. To be more precise, it joins only every third point because Bezier line additionally takes 2 *anchor points* for each point. There are different methods to obtain these points. The simplest one is the following (pictures taken [here](http://www.antigrain.com/research/bezier_interpolation/))

[image]

[image]

[image]

In *Mathematica* it looks like the following code (for an open path)

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {7, 1}};

dist = Norm /@ Differences[pts];
k = 0.5;
coeff = Rest[dist]/(Most[dist] + Rest[dist]);
diff = Differences[pts, 1, 2];
a1 = pts - Join[{{0, 0}}, k (1 - coeff) diff, {{0, 0}}];
a2 = pts + Join[{{0, 0}}, k coeff diff , {{0, 0}}];
bezier = BezierCurve@Flatten[{a1, pts, a2}, {{2, 1}}][[2 ;; -2]];

Graphics[{Darker[Green], Line[pts], Red, Line@Transpose[{a1, a2}], 
  Black, PointSize[0.01], Point[pts], Red, Point@Join[a1, a2], Blue, 
  Thick, bezier}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

For OP's points:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Point[pts], Blue, Thick, bezier}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

You can tune the coefficient `k` to change sharpness of corners.

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I was after - many thanks :)

Comment: How would I add anchor points / line segments to the first and last points of an open path? I have been trying for ages without much success!

Comment: @martin `BezierCurve` takes point1, right anchor for the point1, left anchor for the point2, point2, right anchor for the point2 and so on.

Comment: great - ok thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
llp = ListLinePlot[points, ImageSize -> 500];
llp2 = llp /. Line[x___] :> BSplineCurve[x, SplineDegree -> 2];
Row[{llp, llp2}]
```

[image]

where

```
points = {{-0.137445, -0.0103507}, {-0.0452845,  0.0343154}, {0.30498, -0.0118266}, 
          {-0.0224633, 0.0197979}, {-0.168469, -0.0197066}, {0.0973217, 0.0478612}, 
          {-0.0441388, 0.0360607}, {0.185982, -0.0679699}, {0.0185057,  0.0245944}, 
          {-0.129016,  0.0581276}, {0.0759223, -0.0514376}, {0.123763,  0.0743706},
          {-0.0324282, 0.0267871}, {-0.107764, -0.100215}, {0.0885256,  0.0232463},
          {-0.0353817, 0.110461}, {-0.111862, -0.00308756}, {0.267131, -0.0401582},
          {0.0665588, 0.0494041}, {-0.103328,  0.0535261}, {-0.107966, -0.105811}, 
          {0.112237,  0.0221174}, {0.0250018, 0.153274}, {-0.0569079,  0.0282354}, 
          {0.0635016, -0.142617}, {0.146519,  0.027247}, {-0.0235671, 0.0778935}, 
          {-0.167359,  0.0314445}, {0.0472315, -0.0944644}, {0.166657, 0.0808811}, 
          {0.0127167, 0.126777}, {-0.0896872,  0.00085879}, {0.0468778, -0.181101},
          {0.0641557, 0.00642259}, {-0.00698507, 0.172202}, {-0.112879, 0.0671148},
          {-0.00809596, -0.12273}, {0.211062, 0.0186191}, {0.0619741, 0.117436}, 
          {-0.0725547,  0.0468807}, {-0.129253, -0.139777}, {0.124918, -0.0620453},
          {0.0761669, 0.129845}, {-0.0510648, 0.1879}, {-0.063928, -0.0156006}, 
          {0.133047, -0.178149}, {0.140128, 0.0330165}, {0.00229768, 0.129346}, 
          {-0.122887, 0.0639973}, {-0.079265, -0.156894}};
```

Comment: great! thank you!

Comment: @martin, my pleasure..

Comment: I have noticed on some points the spline changes direction - is it possible to specify that the points are always joined by anticlockwise curve, for example? (Even if another circuit has to be made?)

Comment: ... It does seem to avoid this behaviour if I drop points 1-10 though

Comment: @martin, there a quite a few  possibilities to play with the option settings (`SplineDegree`, `SplineKnots`, `SplineWeights`). Not sure what the right option settings would like to get something close to the second picture in your post.

Comment: Great - thanks for your help - will take a look at the options you mentioned :)

Comment: The splines approximate, but don't actually pass *through* all points (only seemingly the first and last specified). Is there a way of doing this? (See question update.)

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, one can use [J.M.'s nice implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898/280) of a spline with centripetal parametrization which gives (IMO) a "natural" and undisturbed curve.

belisarius has packed J.M.'s code into a function in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40174/280) answer (which would be much more suitable here than in [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40163/280) thread because despite large number of upvotes it does not answer the original question).

I have shortened and redesigned belisarius's code:

```
ClearAll[toSplineData];
toSplineData[data_, order_, prec_] /; MatrixQ[data, NumericQ] := 
 Module[{tvals, bas, ctrlpts, knots, l = Length[data]}, 
  tvals = FoldList[Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[data])^(1/2), Total]];
  (*knots for interpolating B-spline*)
  knots = Join[ConstantArray[0, order + 1], 
               MovingAverage[ArrayPad[tvals, -1], order], 
               ConstantArray[1, order + 1]];
  (*basis function matrix*)
  bas = Table[BSplineBasis[{order, knots}, j - 1, N[tvals[[i]], prec]], {i, l}, {j, l}];
  ctrlpts = LinearSolve[bas, data];
  {ctrlpts, order, knots}]
```

Now the function `toSplineData` can be used in the following ways:

```
{ctrlpts, m, knots} = toSplineData[points, 5, MachinePrecision];

plot = ParametricPlot[
  BSplineFunction[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> m, SplineKnots -> knots][t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Axes -> None, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium,
  Epilog -> {Directive[Green, AbsolutePointSize[6]], Point[points]}]
```

> [image: plot]

```
Graphics[{{Blue, Thick, 
           BSplineCurve[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> m, SplineKnots -> knots]}}, Options@plot]
```

> [image: plot2]

Please note that this function does not have all the flexibility of J.M.'s original code.

Comment: Very nice! Looking forward to testing :)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to force `Interpolation` to construct a differentiable interpolation is to specify derivatives at the interior points.  To get a good curvature, I used 70% of the vector (difference) between the points adjacent to a given point.

```
xyfn = Interpolation @ Thread @
    {List /@ Range @ Length @ points,
     points,
     Join[{Automatic}, 0.7 Differences[points, 1, 2], {Automatic}]};

ParametricPlot[xyfn[t], {t, 1, Length @ points}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], 
   Point[points, VertexColors -> Hue /@ Rescale @ Range @ Length @ points]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: great! Lots to experiment with now!