# BSpline or other curve through arbitrary ordered sequence of two-dimensional points

Tags: fitting, interpolation, splines

How does one create a `BSplineCurve` or other smooth curve *passing through* each point in an ordered list, where the curve may be non-simple, i.e., can double-back upon itself, loop, and so forth as for `{{0,0},{1,0},{.5, 1}, {-1,-2},{1,3}}`?

`BSplineCurve`, `BezierCurve` and related functions use *control points*, but these are not the target points through which the curve must pass.

Comment: This two links can help you http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/how-to-make-bsplinefunction-pass-each-data-point-and-naturally-smooth/26901#26901 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60619/joining-ordered-set-of-points-with-splines-in-spiral

Comment: @DavidG.Stork a recreational (definitely not serious) application showing curves doubling back using second of PlatoManiac's hyperlinks: https://ubpdqnmathematica.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/ubpdqn.gif

Comment: About the *built-in*  `BSplineCurve[]`, you need to give the **control points**. However, to make the **interpolation points** pass the B-spline curve, you must set the **linear-equation** to solve the **control points**.

Comment: @J. M.:  Nope.  Your link is to a *function* (e.g., $f(x)$) and cannot apply to the case where the sequence of points forms a spiral, for instance.

Comment: Actually, it will work. Maybe I should write an answer to make it explicit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it with `Interpolation[]` by expanding the list with a parameter value:

```
l = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, 1}, {-1, -2}, {1, 3}};
f = Interpolation[Table[{i, l[[i]]}, {i, Length@l}], InterpolationOrder -> #] & /@ {3, 4};
Row[ParametricPlot[f[[#]][t], {t, 1, Length@l}, 
                   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@l},  AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ {1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: By the way, `Method -> "Spline"` will create a differentiable curve even with the default `InterpolationOrder -> 3`.

Answer (score 1):

As a proof of concept that the procedure in my [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898) straightforwardly carries to this case, allow me to present a short demo:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, 1}, {-1, -2}, {1, 3}};
tvals = parametrizeCurve[pts, 1]; (* chord-length parametrization, just to be ornery *)
m = 3; (*degree of the B-spline*) n = Length[pts];
(*knots for interpolating B-spline*)
knots = Join[ConstantArray[0, m + 1], 
             MovingAverage[ArrayPad[tvals, -1], m], ConstantArray[1, m + 1]];
(*basis function matrix*)
bas = Outer[BSplineBasis[{m, knots}, #2, #1] &, tvals, Range[0, n - 1]];
ctrlpts = LinearSolve[bas, pts];

Graphics[{Blue, BSplineCurve[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> m, SplineKnots -> knots],
          {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Red], Point[pts]}},
         PlotRange -> {{-5/4, 5/4}, {-11/2, 7/2}}]
```

[image: some spline]